# ¿Cómo acceder a borradores de correo desde Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Estoy creando una `script` para enviar correos mediante combinación de correspondencia, pero para este fin requiero acceder a los borradores de correos de Gmail para que a partir de uno de éstos, pueda hacer la combinación de correos y enviarlos a los respectivos destinatarios.

Se que existen algunas herramientas como complementos para enviar correos combinados pero requiero desarrollar una nueva `script` porque ninguno de ellos tiene los requerimientos de acuerdo a mis necesidades.

¿Cómo desde GAS puedo acceder a estos borradores de correo?

Comment: Es relativamente fácil acceder a los borradores, revisa la clase [`GmailDraft`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft). E indica lo que has investigado/intentado. Además faltan detalles en tu pregunta, puede haber varios borradores, ¿cómo determinas cuál de ellos habrá que escoger?

Answer (score 0):

Usa `GmailApp.getDrafts()`. Los detalles en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getdrafts

Este método devuelve `GmailDraft[]` — un array de JavaScript de borradores de Gmail.